# How to clone a solution in Visual Studio Online?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have various solutions checked in to a VSTS online account.
Sometimes I have the need to create a new solution from a copy of the code of another, and then to check this back in to VSTS to work on as a separate project.

Is there an easy way to do this in Visual Studio?

In *Source Control Explorer* there is the **Move** option, but why not a **Copy** option?

(I am not talking about branching)

Comment: You can copy the solution directly in File Explorer, rename and then add the copied files to source control.

Answer (score 0):

Move is a in effect a combined operation done atomically by TFS. Its essentially a delete and rename. It also retains history.

The following image shows moving a file and then moving it back. You can see the change to see what TFS did to the file.

[image]

If you are talking about taking code files from one location and copying to another, it's essentially a local file level operation. From a TFS point of view, it would be simply an "add" operation that you would need to do explicitly.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to create a copy of an existing folder on the TFS server without getting everything out and then adding it back in?

Comment: yes that's right. Unless you want to do create a new branch

Answer (score 0):

Copy does not make much sense when using a source control system.

As suggested by others you can make a branch, as this will give you the result you want. This could be seen as a copy, besides it not taking up space for the duplicated files.

Comment: Think of the code base as a white label template for new code bases that will become something different.  A branch is not what I need

Comment: Then you might be trying to use the wrong tool for the job.